# How to add tooltip for table column?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

How to add tooltip for table column or row?

UPD:

I have a table. And I want to add tooltip for cell (column) or row like for textfield [image: example]

Comment: You need to provide some more details for this question.

Comment: Just to consider the case of adding a ToolTip to the TableColumn itself (meaning the header of a column): unfortunately, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip can be set by calling `setToolTip` method.

Comment: Where I can find this method in my case?

Comment: I am not sure what Table object you are using. If you are using `javafx.scene.control.TableView` then this class has method `setToolTip`inherited from `javafx.scene.control.Control` class. Check this as well..http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html#setTooltip(javafx.scene.control.Tooltip)

Comment: Check this for tableCell : `javafx.scene.control.TableCell`. This class indirectly inherits the `setToolTip` method. http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableCell.html

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

In my case:

```
mycolumn.setCellFactory(
   new Callback<TableColumn<MyModel, String>, TableCell<MyModel, String>>() {
      @Override
      public TableCell<MyModel,String> call(TableColumn<MyModel,String> tableColumn){
         return new TextFieldTableCell<MyModel, String>() {
            @Override public void updateItem(String string, boolean isEmpty) {
               super.updateItem(string, isEmpty);
               if (!isEmpty) {
                  MyModel model =
                     getTableView().getItems().get(getTableRow().getIndex());
                  Tooltip tip = new Tooltip(model.getTip());
                  setTooltip(tip);
               }
            }
         };
      }});
```